# What word can I use to describe the new or used state of a vehicle?

Tags: word-choice

I am building a web page that lists vehicles for sale, and one of the criteria I would like to list is whether the vehicle is new or used. Currently the best label I can come up with is "New or Used", but there must be a better label that I can use.

Note that this word would serve as a hypernym for `new` and `used`.

Example:

> New or Used: Used

Comment: What's wrong with the terms "New" and "Used"? These are well-established terms in the car trade that have clear meanings. In my opinion, they cannot be improved upon.

Comment: @ErikKowal I think OP is looking for a hypernym under which he can specify whether the car's X is "New" or "Used".

Answer (score 3):

How about the "condition" of the car? ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/condition))

> The state of something with regard to its appearance, quality, or working order:

It could be brand new. Or previously used. (Or, as we call it in India, pre-owned)

**EDIT:** [Newness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/new?q=newness#new__34) is defined by oxford dictionary. maybe you could use that.

[State](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/state) could also be a candidate

Comment: Well, yes, except *condition* could be "immaculate" or "Category A write-off"

Comment: Currently we make use of condition for the vehicles physical condition, possible source of confusion for our users as this seems to be a pretty standard use of the label condition.

Comment: @AlnDvs: see edit